# How to make Dia (which uses X11 / XQuartz) work?

Tags: homebrew, script, x11

When installing Dia, either through `brew install dia` or downloading the DMG from the Dia site, I could run it once. On the second run, I got this:

```
(dia-bin:5065): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.uyECihtczT/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

and Dia won't run.

I don't know how MacOS / X11 integration works, and why it would start once but not after.

I tried to follow some ideas by altering the `dia` launching script as described [here](http://navkirats.blogspot.com/2014/10/dia-diagram-mac-osx-yosemite-fix-i-use.html), but MacOS, being cleverer than needed, doesn't let me run it as the app's files are signed.

How can I fix this and allow MacOS to run it?

Answer (score 4):

This Q & A helped: [Dia command line not working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56749/dia-command-line-not-working)

In short:

1. Copy the script to avoid MacOS preventing running it because of signature mismatch.
2. Add these 2 lines just before the `exec` line:

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0           # Fixes the "cannot open display".
   export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"   # Fixes the annoying Xterm window opening.

   exec "$CWD/dia-bin" --integrated
   ```
3. Run it from a command-line (or make a shortcut to taskbar, if you know how)

   /Applications/Dia.app/Contents/Resources/bin/dia2